# Prove $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)= \sqrt\pi$, using $\Gamma(p)\Gamma(1-p) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi p)}$

Tags: gamma-function

Prove that $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)= \sqrt\pi$

Using $$\Gamma(p)\Gamma(1-p) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi p)}$$

Comment: Hint: what is $\sin(\pi/2)$?

Comment: @Sid: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Answer (score 10):

Let $p=\frac12$, we have
$$\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\frac{\pi}{2}}=\pi$$
therefore
$$\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\sqrt \pi$$

Comment: (Because $\Gamma>0$. This is trivial, but forgetting that the square is not injective is often cause of problems)